# Running Macros with Microsoft Graph

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to run Excel Macros through the Microsoft Graph Excel API. I read through the documentation (https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/excel) but couldn't find anything related to Macros. 
Is there a way of executing my Excel Macros somehow via Microsoft Graph?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can't run your Excel macros from the Microsoft Graph Excel API. You will need to rewrite them to use the Microsoft Graph Excel API. In the meantime, you could voice your request for this feature at <s>https://officespdev.uservoice.com/</s>.

**Update**

Microsoft Graph has a new user voice home:
https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests

Comment: We have a need to run macros programmatically (without VBA code) since these macros are coded by our client users and we can't ask every one of them to transform their code to use graph api's. Is there a way out? I can't find any request in the uservoice.